# Check validation directly on the model

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have just started to "play" with Play framework (2.0) and I'm having some trouble to find a solution to validate models directly. I have googled the problem but I can't find any examples.

In Rails you can check if a model is valid by writing like this: my_model.valid?

I have only seen examples where I can validate the models in the controller but that's not what I want to do right now when I'm writing unit tests.

It would be nice to have myModel.isValid(); or something similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a `validate` method on your Java model classes. See the corresponding [documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaForms).

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't help much. It's seems like I have to reimplement the validations in that method even though I have already annotated the field as required. It is also possible to save the object even if validate method returns a string. Of course I can implement my own "save if validation is ok" method but that's not very developer friendly compared to Rails (ActiveRecord). Is this the only solution?

Comment: The `validate` method is called if the annotations didn’t raise errors.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this solution with some modifications.

In the model:

```
package models;

import play.data.validation.Constraints;

import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class TestModel {

    @Constraints.Required
    public String requiredField;

    // method for directly models validation
    public static Set<String> validate(Object object, Validator validator) {
        Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(object);
        Set<String> errors = new HashSet<>();
        for(ConstraintViolation<Object> cv : constraintViolations) {
            errors.add(cv.getMessage());
        }
        return errors;
    }
}
```

In the controller:

```
package controllers;

import models.TestModel;
import play.data.validation.Validation;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;

import java.util.Set;

public class Test extends Controller {

    public static Result test() {
        TestModel testModel = new TestModel();
        Set<String> errors = TestModel.validate(testModel, Validation.getValidator());
        if(!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return badRequest();
        }
        return ok();
    }

}
```